# Wanderers of Time & Next of Kin Cover artist

Tags: story-identification, history-of, cover-art

I was looking through Amazon for a new science fiction to purchase. I came across the book *[Wanderers of Time](http://rjdent.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/wyndham-wanderers.jpg)* by John Wyndham and noticed the cover art looked rather familiar.

So I went to my book collection and found *[Next of Kin](http://www.flickr.com/photos/emperordalek/1377667390/lightbox/)* by Eric Frank Russell. The cover-art's space ships had so many similarities they had to be by the same artist.

I looked at both of publications of the books according to its book publisher's publish date and found even more evidence to help back up that the artists are the same. *Wanderers of Time* copy was published in 1973 (under Coronet science fiction) and *Next of Kin* was in 1973 (under Sphere Books). Same year interesting eh?

Well I was wondering if anyone knew any information about the artists of these cover arts or can varify that they are the same artists.

Comment: Next of Kin turned out to be a great book. I really enjoyed Russell's writing style. I would recommend this book to anyone looking for a space scout pilot who get captured on an enemies planet and uses his wit to figure out how to get off this planet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking that it's probably [Chris Foss](http://www.chrisfossart.com/)

he pretty much did most of the covers on Sci-Fi books in the 70s and 80s.

I've actually got the Wyndham book at home, will verify the artist (usualy credited in small print on the back cover in those days)

Comment: It has to be Chris Foss, that first spaceship on his page looks exactly like the other two covers. I looked all over Next of Kin, but couldn't find his name. I wonder if you'll have more luck. Thank you Stu!

Comment: According to this site (http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1316526) Chris is the artist for Next of Kin and same for Wanderers of time. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?297726

Comment: Lives on my island, Guernsey, near France and still active - did some work on Guardians of the Galaxy in 2014.

Answer (score 5):

I actually contacted Chris and his daughter so kindly verified it is his art. So she posted Next of Kin on his [site](http://www.chrisfossart.com/2012/03/next-of-kin/) for me. They are in the process of finding a Hi-Res version for Wanderers of time.

For any fan-boy's out there of Chris Foss, here are the direct quotes from his daughter (which can also be found on [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/ChrisFossArt)).

> Hello John, thanks for the question and even better for answering it!
>   I'll have a look and see if we have a good copy of that cover and
>   upload it to the site if we do - but it does ring a bell. I'm slowly
>   uploading book covers and artwork when I get the time. A twitter link
>   will appear here once it's on the site. Do post a comment on
>   ChrisFossArt.com or here if there are any other book covers you'd like
>   to see. All best, Imogene (Chris' daughter).

Comment: Good, except the link to the FB comment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's Chris Foss, no question. If you zoom in, you see Foss's signature logo, an F in a shield. It's at bottom right of the "Wanderers" and bottom left of the "Next of Kin"

Comment: Can you provide images or citations that that is his logo and examples of them on the covers?